# C3.js - Nested JSON objects, How to access and load data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, d3.js, c3.js

guys,

I have the following JsonResult

[JsonResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCnUt.png)

And i use this code to render my chart

```
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: "#graficoProjeto",
        x: 'x',
        data: {
            url: '/AdminOrdemServico/OrdemServProjetos',
            mimeType: 'json',
            xFormat: '%d/%m/%Y',
            keys: {
                x: 'DataEmiss',
                value: ['TotalOs']
            },
            type: 'bar'
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    format: '%d/%m/%Y'
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And how can you see [Chart on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJVKc.png), it's working.
But i need to add a new line for the object inside the json called "OrdemServMot" and the values of this object, to make like this [Combination Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHlHM.png), how can i do this ? thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Latest c3.js version should allow you to specify value "path" instead of just value key. This can help you taking deep values from json structure.
2. To have different chart types, use type**s** instead of type.

   ```
   data: {
       url: '/AdminOrdemServico/OrdemServProjetos',
       mimeType: 'json',
       xFormat: '%d/%m/%Y',
       keys: {
           x: 'DataEmiss',
           value: ['TotalOs', 'OrdemServMot[0].TotalOs'] // 1
       },
       types: ['bar', 'line'] // 2
   },
   ```

Good luck!